# How to add background color for apexcharts y-axis?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, apexcharts

Using apex chart

My code - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z13dbxvk/)

```js
var options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'PRODUCT A',
    data: [44, 55, 41, 67, 22, 43]
  }, {
    name: 'PRODUCT B',
    data: [13, 23, 20, 8, 13, 27]
  }, {
    name: 'PRODUCT C',
    data: [11, 17, 15, 15, 21, 14]
  }, {
    name: 'PRODUCT D',
    data: [21, 7, 25, 13, 22, 8]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 350,
    stacked: true,
    toolbar: {
      show: true
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 480,
    options: {
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
        offsetX: -10,
        offsetY: 0
      }
    }
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      borderRadius: 8,
      horizontal: false,
    },
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: ['01/01/2011 GMT', '01/02/2011 GMT', '01/03/2011 GMT', '01/04/2011 GMT',
      '01/05/2011 GMT', '01/06/2011 GMT'
    ],
  },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontSize: "12px",
        fontWeight: 400,
        fontFamily: "Open Sans",
        colors: ["#7286EA"],
        backgroundColor: '#e7e7e7',
        },
      },
   },
  
  legend: {
    position: 'right',
    offsetY: 40
  },
  fill: {
    opacity: 1
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<div id="chart" class="apex-charts" dir="ltr"></div>
```

Add for `yaxis labels style` - `backgroundColor: '#e7e7e7'` - but it doesn't work

I try to do as in the image
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to add background color for Apexcharts y-axis?

You can add a background playing with javascript and the SVG Apexcharts made.

You can access the SVG they create through `querySelector` then add elements or other tricks you could think of to make it the way you want.

This lets you be very flexible and do exactly what you want.

```js
   var options = {
    series: [
      {
        name: 'PRODUCT A',
        data: [44, 55, 41, 67, 22, 43]
      },
      {
        name: 'PRODUCT B',
        data: [13, 23, 20, 8, 13, 27]
      },
      {
        name: 'PRODUCT C',
        data: [11, 17, 15, 15, 21, 14]
      },
      {
        name: 'PRODUCT D',
        data: [21, 7, 25, 13, 22, 8]
      }
    ],
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      height: 350,
      stacked: true,
      toolbar: {
        show: true
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: true
      },
      events: {
        mounted: function() {
          addYAxisBackground()
        },
        updated: function() {
          addYAxisBackground()
        }
      }
    },
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        options: {
          legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            offsetX: -10,
            offsetY: 0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        borderRadius: 8,
        horizontal: false
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      categories: [
        '01/01/2011 GMT',
        '01/02/2011 GMT',
        '01/03/2011 GMT',
        '01/04/2011 GMT',
        '01/05/2011 GMT',
        '01/06/2011 GMT'
      ]
    },
    yaxis: {
      labels: {
        style: {
          fontSize: '12px',
          fontWeight: 400,
          fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
          colors: ['#7286EA'],
          backgroundColor: '#e7e7e7'
        }
      }
    },

    legend: {
      position: 'right',
      offsetY: 40
    },
    fill: {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }

  var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options)
  chart.render()

  function addYAxisBackground() {
    var ctx = document.querySelector('svg'),
      textElm = ctx.querySelector('svg g'),
      SVGRect = textElm.getBBox()

    var rect = document.createElementNS(
      'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
      'rect'
    )
    rect.setAttribute('x', SVGRect.x)
    rect.setAttribute('y', SVGRect.y)
    rect.setAttribute('width', '90px')
    rect.setAttribute('height', SVGRect.height + 20)
    rect.setAttribute('fill', 'yellow')
    ctx.insertBefore(rect, textElm)
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<div id="chart" class="apex-charts" dir="ltr"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I just used inspect and found the svg class for yaxis("apexcharts-yaxis-texts-g") and appended  in  it ,after trying some values  made a rectangle which would somewhat cover the y-axis making it look like a background.

#### This might work for u.

Edit: Due to appending an element dynamically if the window is resized it would make that  element disappeared, for that I used resize event which would fire a function after 500ms to re-add that element.

This counter of 500 ms gets restarted whenever there is a change in the window's dimensions (as we clear the timeout) so the function will only be called if the user stops resizing the window or if the user resizes the window VERY slowly which doesn't happens normally.

```js
var options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'sales',
    data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91, 125]
  }],
  xaxis: {
    categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]
  }
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();

var set = document.getElementsByClassName('apexcharts-yaxis-texts-g')[0];
var node = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
node.setAttribute('height', '91%');
node.setAttribute('width', '5%');
node.setAttribute('fill', 'cyan');


set.insertBefore(node, set.childNodes[0]);

var func;

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
  clearTimeout(func);
func = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
})

function doneResizing(){
var set=document.getElementsByClassName('apexcharts-yaxis-texts-g')[0];
var node = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","rect");
node.setAttribute('height','91%');
node.setAttribute('width','5%');
node.setAttribute('fill','cyan');


set.insertBefore(node, set.childNodes[0]);  
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

#chart {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 35px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<div id="chart">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation, there is no `backgroundColor` as an option for `yaxis.labels.style`. `yaxis.labels.style` has the following options:

```
{
  colors: [],
  fontSize: '12px',
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
  fontWeight: 400,
  cssClass: 'apexcharts-yaxis-label'
}
```

Here are the Docs: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/yaxis/#formatter

Comment: Thanks, so it is not possible to do this?

Comment: I don't know. I just checked the Docs and post it here. I would say that they would put it in the Docs if it is one of the options. You should wait for other answers. Maybe someone will know more.

Comment: can't we add an extra css class to `cssClass` here ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do this by using CSS variables and background.

```js
function updateBackground() {
  const chart = document.querySelector('.apexcharts-canvas');
  const yAxis = document.querySelector('.apexcharts-yaxis');
  const transform = yAxis.getAttribute('transform');
  const translateX = transform.slice(transform.indexOf('(') + 1, transform.indexOf(','));
  
  const yAxisBBox = yAxis.getBBox();
  // console.log('yAxisBBox', yAxisBBox);
  
  chart.style.setProperty('--width', yAxisBBox.width + 'px');
  chart.style.setProperty('--x', (+translateX + yAxisBBox.x) + 'px');
}

var options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'PRODUCT A',
    data: [44, 55, 41, 67, 22, 43]
  }, {
    name: 'PRODUCT B',
    data: [13, 23, 20, 8, 13, 27]
  }, {
    name: 'PRODUCT C',
    data: [11, 17, 15, 15, 21, 14]
  }, {
    name: 'PRODUCT D',
    data: [21, 7, 25, 13, 22, 8]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 350,
    stacked: true,
    toolbar: {
      show: true
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true
    },
    events: {
      /* run the function on mounted and updated hooks */
      mounted: updateBackground,
      updated: updateBackground
    }
  },
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 480,
    options: {
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
        offsetX: -10,
        offsetY: 0
      }
    }
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      borderRadius: 8,
      horizontal: false,
    },
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: ['01/01/2011 GMT', '01/02/2011 GMT', '01/03/2011 GMT', '01/04/2011 GMT',
      '01/05/2011 GMT', '01/06/2011 GMT'
    ],
  },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontSize: "12px",
        fontWeight: 400,
        fontFamily: "Open Sans",
        colors: ["#7286EA"],
        backgroundColor: '#e7e7e7',
      },
    },
  },

  legend: {
    position: 'right',
    offsetY: 40
  },
  fill: {
    opacity: 1
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```css
.apexcharts-canvas {
  --padding-x: 10px; /* you can change this by 0 or anything you want */
  background-image: linear-gradient(yellow, yellow);
  background-position: calc(var(--x) - var(--padding-x)) 0;
  background-size: calc(var(--width) + var(--padding-x) * 2) 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<div id="chart" class="apex-charts" dir="ltr"></div>
```

Cover exact area:

```js
function updateBackground() {
  const chart = document.querySelector('.apexcharts-canvas');
  const yAxis = document.querySelector('.apexcharts-yaxis');
  const transform = yAxis.getAttribute('transform');
  const translateX = transform.slice(transform.indexOf('(') + 1, transform.indexOf(','));
  
  const yAxisBBox = yAxis.getBBox();
  // console.log('yAxisBBox', yAxisBBox);
  
  chart.style.setProperty('--width', yAxisBBox.width + 'px');
  chart.style.setProperty('--height', yAxisBBox.height + 'px');
  chart.style.setProperty('--x', (+translateX + yAxisBBox.x) + 'px');
  chart.style.setProperty('--y', yAxisBBox.y + 'px');
}

var options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'PRODUCT A',
    data: [44, 55, 41, 67, 22, 43]
  }, {
    name: 'PRODUCT B',
    data: [13, 23, 20, 8, 13, 27]
  }, {
    name: 'PRODUCT C',
    data: [11, 17, 15, 15, 21, 14]
  }, {
    name: 'PRODUCT D',
    data: [21, 7, 25, 13, 22, 8]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 350,
    stacked: true,
    toolbar: {
      show: true
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true
    },
    events: {
      /* run the function on mounted and updated hooks */
      mounted: updateBackground,
      updated: updateBackground
    }
  },
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 480,
    options: {
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
        offsetX: -10,
        offsetY: 0
      }
    }
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      borderRadius: 8,
      horizontal: false,
    },
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: ['01/01/2011 GMT', '01/02/2011 GMT', '01/03/2011 GMT', '01/04/2011 GMT',
      '01/05/2011 GMT', '01/06/2011 GMT'
    ],
  },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontSize: "12px",
        fontWeight: 400,
        fontFamily: "Open Sans",
        colors: ["#7286EA"],
        backgroundColor: '#e7e7e7',
      },
    },
  },

  legend: {
    position: 'right',
    offsetY: 40
  },
  fill: {
    opacity: 1
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```css
.apexcharts-canvas {
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, yellow) var(--x) var(--y) / var(--width) var(--height) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<div id="chart" class="apex-charts" dir="ltr"></div>
```